# vb.net GetDirectories Loading Spinner

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I currently have a function that gets the directories and some images located in those directories and stores them in a listview.

The problem is that there is 1000+ directories which causes the app to hang as they are all loading. I am wondering how i would go about displaying a loading spinner gif until it is done? I tried setting the visibility of the gif to visible at the start of the function and then at the end, it would set it to hidden again, but it just seems to set it to hidden straight away instead of waiting until the listview is populated.

Here is some code, it has been amended to only relevant parts as the original function is far too long.

```
Private Function loaditems(Optional dir As String = "\")
        listview.Items.Clear()
                Dim filePaths As String() = Directory.GetDirectories(dir, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                For Each filePath As String In filePaths
                        If (File.GetAttributes(filePath) And FileAttributes.Hidden) <> FileAttributes.Hidden Then
                            Dim foldername As String = filePath.Split("\")(4)
                            listview.Items.Add(New With {Key .img = filePath & "\myimage.jpg", .name = foldername, .path = filePath, .created = Directory.GetCreationTime(filePath)})
                        End If
                Next
        Return False
End Function
```

Comment: Look into putting your time consuming work into a background worker to do your heavy lifting. This will stop your UI from freezing/non responsive. Having an animated gif wont do much either if its created on the UI thread as it wont spin... this can be resolved by using a background worker. Start it in the dowork and in the workercompleted you can stop/close the spinner. Its much easier to create your own spinner class/control as well so it can be reused anywhere you need it as well...

Comment: So when i want to run the function i should run the worked instead? what about the parameters being passed to the function?